# How to implement a multilayer playback?

Tags: ios, video, time, timeline

I am currently building a timeline-based app, in which the user can layer certain actions (video clips, sounds) and playback them.

My question is: How would I go about building this time-based playback?
I thought about adding a timers for every action, firing at the desired time or just a asyncAfter(:).

Comment: I don't think it is events what you are after, it is more static info. I guess i'd have a List called timeline, this list has one entry per frame step and thee entry itself is again a List of stuff to be played (filename, timecode)

Comment: As of right now, I have it set up similarly, except the list only contains events and their timestamp. So there are no entries where nothing happens. The playback timer runs every millisecond and calls a handleEvents method, in which it tests if the next event's timestamp is smaller or equal to the current playback time and executes any actions if needed. Don't know if this polling-like method is wasting cpu power.

Comment: Does not sound too bad. The only thing that comes to my mind is that typical timelines define their output framerate at creation time. Sure any item in the playlist has to match this framerate or be converted up in front. This way, you only need to call your events every frame step instead of every millisecond. But in the end these days we have lots of CPU power that allow us to introduce new ways with new features ;-) I guess there is no answer to this topic as it all depends on your requirements but i wish you all the best my friend!